# In python MRJob, how to set up the option for tempory output directory

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, mrjob

I am using MRJob to run the very simple word count as a standard hadoop job:

```
python word_count.py -r hadoop hdfs:///path-to-my-data
```

This print error indicating that it can not create the temporary directory for temporary output:

```
STDERR: mkdir: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///user/path-to-tmp-dir
...
...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/hadoop', 'fs', '-mkdir', 'hdfs:///user/
```

Assume I can not create the directory desired by default by MRJob. Is it possible to pass the option to MRJob through command line? The only option I found so far is the [base_tmp_dir](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/configs-all-runners.html#option-base_tmp_dir). In the description it mentioned "Path to put local temp dirs inside." where the "local" is not exactly what I am looking for as the temporary output directory is supposed to be in hdfs. Nevertheless, I meant to give it a try (:

```
python word_count.py --base-tmp-dir=./tmp/ data.txt
```

or

```
python word_count.py -r hadoop --base-tmp-dir=hdfs:///some-path hdfs:///path-to-data
```

but failed as the MRJob complain there is no such option:

```
word_count.py: error: no such option: --base-tmp-dir
```

The `word_count.py` is the standard one found [here](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/quickstart.html#writing-your-first-job). May be I am missing some essential knowledge on MRJobj or I may have to go back to hadoop streaming.

Answer (score 1):

`mrjob` calls the `hadoop` binary when interacting with HDFS. The `hadoop` command needs to know where the NameNode is located on the network so URIs like `hdfs:///some-path` don't require the full host (something like `hdfs://your-namenode:9000/some-path`. The command figures out where the NameNode is by reading your configuration XML files.

There's lots of [conflicting reports on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=hadoop_prefix&oq=hadoop_prefix) about [which environment variable](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/issues/844) to set, but in my environment running the latest version of mrjob and Apache Hadoop 2.4.1, I had to set the `HADOOP_PREFIX` environment variables. You can set this with the command:

`export HADOOP_PREFIX=/path/to/your/hadoop`

Once this is set, you'll know this is set correctly if you type:

`ls $HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop`

and this shows your configuration XML files.

Now run your command. It should work.